# Get Organisation Unit from Account ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-organizations

In terraform is there a way (data source etc.) to extract Organization Unit (OU) from ID of the account that belongs to that OU?

I can extract various pieces of information from

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}
```

or

```
data "aws_iam_session_context" "current" {}
```

But no OU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find direct way to do this in terraform, but found out that CLI command [list-parents](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/organizations/list-parents.html) exists that I could use in conjunction with terraform. Until terraform adds this datasource I will go this way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a data source for OUs: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/organizations_organizational_units.

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for. This data source takes parent OU id as a parameter and lists children OU under it. I need to get OU by AWS account ID that belongs to it.

Comment: Any reason in particular that requires such a correlation?

Comment: I am using OU id as a condition for an AIM policy, the policy is being applied inside of a nested module that is being used multiple times throughout the project. Technically I _could_ pass OU id as a variable, but this means adding this variable in many places at many levels of nesting. Ideally OU id should be determined at runtime and only in one place - where the policy is defined. And I do know account ID at runtime.

Comment: I have looked also for any other API calls that could be made but none of those is using AWS account ID as input. There is another data source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/organizations_organization. I'm not sure if what you want is possible though.

Comment: Thanks, this comes closer to what I need. It gives can give you list of accounts within the org, and I could use account id to lookup info for the account I need. I'd give me `arn`, `email`, `id`, `name`, and `status` for the account. But unfortunately no ou.